# How to get pine sap off my teeth

Tags: health

I wanted to emulate old sap gum but it seems I have chewed some sap that was premature.

Now it has covered my gums and teeth. How on earth do I remove this stuff?

What I have tried:

Brushing (slow, damages brush)
Isopropyl Alcohol (too painful)
Ethanol Alcohol (negligible effect)
Picking (works slowly, doesn't get rid of everything)
Flossing (same as picking)
Oil (negligible effect)

I'm out of ideas... This is really not doing my teeth any good.

Comment: Why on earth have you put tree sap on your teeth?!

Comment: @Liam In the old days that's what people used for chewing gum.

Comment: why on earth does anyone need to chew gum?

Comment: Isopropyl alcohol is toxic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol#Toxicology I'm sure you didn't swallow, but that doesn't necessarily mean you escaped toxicity. If you get any of the symptoms described in the WP article, I would go to the ER. I believe this is treatable, but the consequences can be bad if it's not treated.

Comment: FYI I survived just fine but @user2169's advice probably still holds. dont do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use different methods to remove the pine sap from your teeth. Here are a few:

- Take a small amount of **margarine** and rub on the sap
- Mix a solution of **warm water, salt, and about 3 drops of honey**, keep this mixture in your mouth for about 3minutes
- use some drinkable strong **alcohol** and try to rub it of
- use **oil or peanut butter** and rub it over the sap
- try to let the sap **dry out** and then remove it

Answer (score 12):

Been there, done that, can't remember why it happened..

It will go away in a few days. Eating few apples, or maybe some dry, high-fiber crackers will probably help.